# Spark cannot process dataset larger than memory

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using spark on YARN. 
Setup:

- `spark.sql.partitions=3200`
- 20 executors
- 12Gb+1Gb(memOverhead)/5CPU per executor (~250Gb RAM total)

Simple DAG representation:

1. Read data (partition filter + some filters) - partial dropDuplicates() - exchange
2. exchange - dropDuplicates() - explode, pythonUDF
3. saveAsTable

Some statistics:

1. Input ~250Gb, shuffle write ~ 250Gb
2. Shuffle read ~250Gb (80Mb per task) (so in deserialized form it takes more than that)

Data after exhange is evenly distrubuted (no skewed keys), explode is small (only 1% of data is added, maximum explosion is 200 records), pythonUDF doesn't create complex structures, just url pasrsing.

Stage 2 is failing with `YARN killed executor for running beyond memory limits`.

If i ask for twice more executors it works fine. But that's too expensive for cluster.

The question is "why it does not spill computed data to disk and fails with OOM?"
It is kind of sad, that spark can't process stage with shuffle read larger than RAM, because everything i've read says, that's not the problem and spark can spill to disk and degrade to mapreduce.

Comment: It depends on how you deal with data.

Comment: If you use a bigger number of `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` do you still get the error ? Try going from 80MB per task to 10-20MB.

Comment: Increasing partitions doesn't solve it, tried 6400.

Comment: from where you are reading the data. from s3 or hdfs or any data sources

Comment: HDFS + jdbc from clickhouse (3 queries 1k rows each for broadcast and filter main dataset in stage 1)

Comment: can u please verify jdbc source dataframe partition numbers. df.rdd.getNumPartitions.. if it is 1 , just do repartition for that data frame

Comment: jdbc DataFrames are instantly broadcasted, yes, they have 1 partition when read, but there is only ~1000 rows of 1 integer, can you explain please, how repartitioning them could help?
Stage 1 with this broadcasts works fine, stage 2 is where executors die